# Get TopoDS_Shape from AIS_InteractiveObject

Tags: geometry, opencascade

I'm very new to OPEN CASCADE.
Can someone please let me know how to get the shape from AIS_InteractiveObject which used to view the shapes.
Thanks.

There are no direct functions to get the shapes. I checked with the class discription in Open CASCADE documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your AIS_InteractiveObject called "interactiveObj".
You can downcast this to "AIS_Shape" first.

```
interactiveObj = ... ; // your interactive object
Handle(AIS_Shape) aisShape = Handle(AIS_Shape)::DownCast(interactiveObj ); // convert to AIS_Shape
```

Then you can get the TopoDS_Shape from the object.

```
TopoDS_Shape shape = aisShape->Shape();
```

This is the simple method.

```
TopoDS_Shape shape = Handle(AIS_Shape)::DownCast(interactiveObj)->Shape(); // get the TopoDS_Shape
```